# Set Value of String in Static Class

Tags: c#, webforms

I am trying to set the value of a string in a static class from a button click on an .aspx page.  I am not understanding why the value is always null.

Here is the static class code:

```
public static class XeroApiHelper
{
    private static ApplicationSettings _applicationSettings;
    public static string WebUrl { get; set; }

    static XeroApiHelper()
    {
        // Refer to README.md for details

        string callbackUrl = WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";
```

The string I am trying to set is the `WebUrl`.

Here is the code in the click event:

```
protected void btnXeroConnect_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    string weburl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
    XeroApiHelper.WebUrl = weburl;
    _user = XeroApiHelper.User();
    _authenticator = XeroApiHelper.MvcAuthenticator();
    var authorizeUrl = _authenticator.GetRequestTokenAuthorizeUrl(_user.Name);
    Response.Redirect(authorizeUrl);
}
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It must have something to do with Worker Threads handling requests. Do this. Add a GUID like public static Guid _myId = Guid.New(); in the XeroApiHelper class. Then debug both cases when you assign a value and wen you want to access the value. Check the Id's - guessing they will be different

Comment: Please provide [MCVE] were you use that `WebUrl` value. Obviously code in static constructor shown in the post will always get its initial value... So need code where this `WebUrl` value is used later (after you set global static value to request specific value... which does not really look like a good idea).

Comment: If `XeroApiHelper.WebUrl` is `null` after `XeroApiHelper.WebUrl = weburl;`, then that means `Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);` is returning `null`, right? If not, please clarify exactly where in the code the problem is occurring, and what's the actual exception message.

Comment: @RufusL - No.  The Request.Url.GetLeftPart is returning exactly what it is supposed to, that is why I do not understand why WebUrl is null in the static class.  All "Request.Url.GetLeftPart" does is return the domain.  Which currently is localhost:53476/

Comment: Where in the code shown is it `null`?

Comment: @RufusL - in the class it is null.  This line " string callbackUrl = WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";"

Comment: Well, yes, of course when the contstructor runs it will be null - nothing has set it yet. Perhaps you should make `callbackUrl` a private property instead, and have it return the concatenation of the current value of the `WebUrl` plus the suffix.

Comment: `private static callbackUrl => WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";`

Comment: The constructor runs when it hits this line "XeroApiHelper.WebUrl = weburl;"  So I don't understand why it would be null.  The class code runs when it is set.

Comment: @RufusL - How will this "private static callbackUrl => WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";" work if WebUrl is null?

Comment: Because the constructor is run only the very first time the class is referenced, which is indeed on that line, but *before* the assignment. [Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors)

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Presumably you'd access `callbackUrl` *after* `WebUrl` is set to something.

Comment: This " private static callbackUrl => WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";" throws all sorts of errors.  I don't really understand that.

Comment: Was missing the type: `private static string callbackUrl => WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";` This creates a private property that will have the current value of `WebUrl` when it's accessed, because it does the concatenation on every `get`, as opposed to one where it is only set an initial value once, in the constructor, when `WebUri` is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This because of `static constructor`. The constructor is called before any static member is referenced. That means constructor has been called before line `XeroApiHelper.WebUrl = weburl;` is execute. That sets `null` value in `callbackUrl`

> A static constructor is called automatically to initialize the class
>   before the first instance is created or any static members are
>   referenced. A static constructor will run before an instance
>   constructor. A type's static constructor is called when a static
>   method assigned to an event or a delegate is invoked and not when it
>   is assigned. If static field variable initializers are present in the
>   class of the static constructor, they will be executed in the textual
>   order in which they appear in the class declaration immediately prior
>   to the execution of the static constructor.

[Static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors)

**Edited:** to include possible solution

Move code from `static` constructor to `set` call of `WebUrl` as:

```
private static string _WebUrl;
public static string WebUrl
{
    get { return _WebUrl; }
    set
    {
        _WebUrl = value;
        string  callbackUrl = _WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";
        // move rest of code from constructore here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful info, but I still do not understand how to pass the value of WebUrl.  Is there any way to pass a value here?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff What's wrong with the code sample in the answer? Or the read-only property sample from the comments: `private static string callbackUrl => WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";`? Are they not working?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff What is full details of code of constructor? Why cannot you use static function instead?

Comment: This "private static string callbackUrl => WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";  causes errors on all the code beneath it.  Everything has redlines.  The messages read "cannot declare instance member in a static class.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Whatever code you have in constructor should be shift to `set` method of `WebUrl `

Comment: @MKR - how would I pass the string to a function?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff I have modified my answer to include a possible solution. You can simply move all code from constructor to `set` call.  see  my edited code.

Comment: This " private static string callbackUrl => WebUrl + "/xero/xeroconnection.aspx";" did not work WebUrl is still null.  Trying new solution...

Comment: @MKR - thanks for the assistance.  The solution did not work. When it its "WebUrl = value;" it never moves off of it and causes a stack overflow.

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Have a look at modified answer. I had not mentioned having a `private string `_WebUrl` to store value of `WebUrl`.

Comment: @MKR - Thanks, I used a "work around" for a while until I could get back to testing your final solution.  It worked like a charm!